# javascript self executing syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Did anyone know the code which define like this:

```
!function(window, undefined) {
    // do something
} (window)
```

By searching in google, I can understand the syntax like:

```
function(window, undefined) {
    // do something
} (window)
```

But I don't figure out any article about the syntax have "!" operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!` operator is there so the function is parsed as an *expression*, rather than a *declaration*. Since a declaration cannot be invoked, your second example is a syntax error.

A more commonly seen form is to enclose the function in parentheses:

```
(function(window,undefined) {
    // do something
}(window));
```

That has exactly the same effect, as does the use of any unary operator.

Comment: I think you mean (function(window,undefined) { ... })(window);

Comment: I just came by this thread and was curious. By expression you mean like i.e an if statement? `if (function()) {}`?

Comment: the exclamation mark transform the definition into an expression so that the parenthesis can call it right after because it has higher priority, `!function(){}()` is an evil version of `(function(){})()`

Answer (score 0):

It might be like this.

```
!(function(window, undefined){ /* some code */ })(window);
(function(window, undefined){ /* some code */ })(window);
```